# Slower SQL Server performance after allocating more CPU and RAM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, windows-server

We have SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.1600) running on a virtual Windows 2008 R2 server. After upgrading the CPU from 1 core to 4 and the RAM from 4 gb to 10 gb, we've noticed the performance is worse.

Some observations I see:

1. A query that took <5 seconds to run is now taking >200 seconds.
2. The CPU is pegged at 100 with sqlservr.exe as the culprit.
3. A select count(*) on a table with 4.6 million rows took over 90 seconds.
4. The processes that are running on the server haven't changed. The only change was to increase the cpu and ram.
5. Other sql servers have a static paging file where this server is set to manage it on its own.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Per sp_BlitzErik, I ran

```
EXEC dbo.sp_BlitzFirst @SinceStartup = 1;
```

Giving me these results.

[image: wait stats]

Comment: Last time I saw a similar question on SE, it was because someone turned up the VM CPUs and RAM *but the VM host didn't actually have that many CPUs and that much RAM*. So I'd check that first.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, and most of it is pretty broad and vague.

1. 2008R2 RTM came out on April 21, 2010. It's totally out of support. You'll want to prioritize getting on the latest Service Pack, which came out just about 3 years ago to the day. That way you'll be covered if you're hitting a weird bug or something. Head on [over here](https://sqlserverupdates.com/) to figure out what you need to download.
2. Since you added vCPUs (from 1 to 4) and didn't change any settings, your queries can now go parallel. I know this sounds like they'll all be faster, but hang on!
3. You may have added RAM, but you may not have changed Max Server Memory so your server can take advantage of it.
4. Figure out what your server is waiting on. An open source project I work on provides free scripts to help you measure your SQL Server. Head on [over here](http://firstresponderkit.org) if you wanna give them a try.

You'll wanna grab sp_BlitzFirst to check out your server's wait stats. You can run it a couple ways.

This will show you what your server has been waiting on since it started up.

`EXEC dbo.sp_BlitzFirst @SinceStartup = 1;`

This will show you what queries are waiting on now, during a 30 second window.

`EXEC dbo.sp_BlitzFirst @Seconds = 30, @ExpertMode = 1;`

Once you figure out what queries are waiting on (there's a ton of stuff written about wait stats out there), you can start making changes to get things under control.

If you see them waiting on `CXPACKET`, that means your queries are going parallel, and maybe trampling over each other. If you hit this, you'll probably want to consider bumping Cost Threshold for Parallelism up to 50, and maybe dropping MAXDOP down to 2.

After this step is when you want to use something like [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) or sp_BlitzWho (the latter is in the GitHub repo from earlier) to start capturing query plans. Aside from wait stats, they're one of the most important things you can look at to figure out what's going wrong.

You may also want to check out this article by Jonathan Kehayias about [VMWare Counters](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/monitoring/troubleshooting-cpu-vmware) to check out in relation to SQL Server.

**Update**

Reviewing the wait stats and boy are they weird. There's definitely something up with the CPUs. Your server is mostly sitting around bored, but when things heat up, things get bad. I'll try to break this down easily.

1. You're hitting a [poison wait](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/08/what-are-poison-waits/) called `THREADPOOL`. You don't have a ton of it, but that makes sense because your server isn't terribly active. I'll explain why in a minute.
2. You have really long average waits on `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` and `CXPACKET`. You're on a VM, so you're gonna wanna make sure that the SQL Server has reservations, or that the box isn't horribly oversubscribed. A noisy neighbor can really ruin your day here. You're also going to want to make sure that the server/VM guest/VM host aren't running in Balanced Power mode. This makes your CPUs spin down to unnecessarily low speeds, and they don't immediately spin back up to full speed.
3. How do they tie in? With 4 CPUs you have 512 worker threads. Keep in mind, you had the [same amount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option) with a single CPU, but now that your queries can go parallel, they can consume many more worker threads. In your case 4 threads per parallel branch of a parallel query.

What's going parallel? Most likely everything. The default Cost Threshold for Parallelism is 5. That number was made the default sometime in the late 90s working on a desktop that looked [like this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/dannyr/2008/10/09/what-estimated-subtree-cost-1-means-or-a-great-sql-server-history-story/).

[image: NUTS]

Granted, your hardware is smaller than most laptops, but you're still a bit ahead of that thing.

When lots of parallel queries get going, you're running out of those worker threads. When that happens, queries just sit around waiting for threads to get going. That's also where `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` comes in. Queries are stepping off CPUs and not getting back on for a long time. I don't see any blocking waits, so you're most likely just all stuffed up on intra-query parallelism waits.

What can you do?

1. Make sure nothing is in Balanced Power mode
2. Change MAXDOP to 2
3. Change cost threshold for parallelism to 50
4. Follow the Jon K. article above to validate VM health
5. Use the script called `sp_BlitzIndex` to look for any missing index requests.

For more thorough troubleshooting, check out the [whitepaper I wrote for Google](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/new-white-paper-sql-server-performance-tuning-google-compute-engine/) on hardware sizing in the cloud.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 10):

Yes! I've experienced this type of situation on SQL Server vms in our server farm.  Look at the vm's host CPU ready time and the memory balloon driver counters.
[CPU READY TIME – BLOG PART I](http://houseofbrick.com/cpu-ready-time-blog-part-i/) and 
[Understanding VMware Ballooning](http://www.vfrank.org/2013/09/18/understanding-vmware-ballooning/)
Working with my sysadmin was key, but was not easy...

Answer (score 5):

One thing I didn't see pointed out, is that adding vCPUs to a VM can very often slow it down due to scheduling.

The basic idea is that if a VM has 4 vCPUs, then the hypervisor must wait for 4 physical cores to be available so that is can schedule all of the vCPUs, even if 3 of them are idle.

If you don't have a lot of cores in your host, and your other workloads are busy, this can result in extra waiting, and a significant drop in performance.

In VMware ESXi you can see it in the advanced graphs via CPU Ready.

[Here's one of many articles with a real world example of this happening and how it was diagnosed](http://www.gabesvirtualworld.com/how-too-many-vcpus-can-negatively-affect-your-performance/).

Adding more RAM can also cause a sudden performance drop if the VM's RAM allocation is larger than a NUMA node.

Additionally, the configuration of your vCPUs (vSockets vs. vCores) can actually affect some applications like SQL server. This is because SQL server is itself NUMA aware (to avoid the same kind of NUMA-spanning performance drop) and because VMware may present virtual NUMA nodes differently.

[This is covered in a blog post on VMware's own site](https://blogs.vmware.com/performance/2017/03/virtual-machine-vcpu-and-vnuma-rightsizing-rules-of-thumb.html).

---

This being said, I'm glad you worked out the issues with Erik's help, but you may want to look at and consider these things as well.

Answer (score 4):

Just a Little help ( can't post this as a comment ) continuing  @sp_BlitzErik's answer, I got some queries with Pinal and Max Vernon ( can't rememebr where ) that say how much MAXDOP you should use:

```
/*************************************************************************
Author          :   Kin Shah
Purpose         :   Recommend MaxDop settings for the server instance
Tested RDBMS    :   SQL Server 2008R2

**************************************************************************/
declare @hyperthreadingRatio bit
declare @logicalCPUs int
declare @HTEnabled int
declare @physicalCPU int
declare @SOCKET int
declare @logicalCPUPerNuma int
declare @NoOfNUMA int

select @logicalCPUs = cpu_count -- [Logical CPU Count]
    ,@hyperthreadingRatio = hyperthread_ratio --  [Hyperthread Ratio]
    ,@physicalCPU = cpu_count / hyperthread_ratio -- [Physical CPU Count]
    ,@HTEnabled = case 
        when cpu_count > hyperthread_ratio
            then 1
        else 0
        end -- HTEnabled
from sys.dm_os_sys_info
option (recompile);

select @logicalCPUPerNuma = COUNT(parent_node_id) -- [NumberOfLogicalProcessorsPerNuma]
from sys.dm_os_schedulers
where [status] = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'
    and parent_node_id < 64
group by parent_node_id
option (recompile);

select @NoOfNUMA = count(distinct parent_node_id)
from sys.dm_os_schedulers -- find NO OF NUMA Nodes 
where [status] = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'
    and parent_node_id < 64

-- Report the recommendations ....
select
    --- 8 or less processors and NO HT enabled
    case 
        when @logicalCPUs < 8
            and @HTEnabled = 0
            then 'MAXDOP setting should be : ' + CAST(@logicalCPUs as varchar(3))
                --- 8 or more processors and NO HT enabled
        when @logicalCPUs >= 8
            and @HTEnabled = 0
            then 'MAXDOP setting should be : 8'
                --- 8 or more processors and HT enabled and NO NUMA
        when @logicalCPUs >= 8
            and @HTEnabled = 1
            and @NoofNUMA = 1
            then 'MaxDop setting should be : ' + CAST(@logicalCPUPerNuma / @physicalCPU as varchar(3))
                --- 8 or more processors and HT enabled and NUMA
        when @logicalCPUs >= 8
            and @HTEnabled = 1
            and @NoofNUMA > 1
            then 'MaxDop setting should be : ' + CAST(@logicalCPUPerNuma / @physicalCPU as varchar(3))
        else ''
        end as Recommendations
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------

```
--MAX VERNON 

/* 
   This will recommend a MAXDOP setting appropriate for your machine's NUMA memory
   configuration.  You will need to evaluate this setting in a non-production 
   environment before moving it to production.

   MAXDOP can be configured using:  
   EXEC sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism',X;
   RECONFIGURE

   If this instance is hosting a Sharepoint database, you MUST specify MAXDOP=1 
   (URL wrapped for readability)
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rcormier/archive/2012/10/25/
   you-shall-configure-your-maxdop-when-using-sharepoint-2013.aspx

   Biztalk (all versions, including 2010): 
   MAXDOP = 1 is only required on the BizTalk Message Box
   database server(s), and must not be changed; all other servers hosting other 
   BizTalk Server databases may return this value to 0 if set.
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899000
*/
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CoreCount int;
SET @CoreCount = 0;
DECLARE @NumaNodes int;

/*  see if xp_cmdshell is enabled, so we can try to use 
    PowerShell to determine the real core count
*/
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    name varchar(255)
    , minimum int
    , maximum int
    , config_value int
    , run_value int
);
INSERT INTO @T 
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell';
DECLARE @cmdshellEnabled BIT;
SET @cmdshellEnabled = 0;
SELECT @cmdshellEnabled = 1 
FROM @T
WHERE run_value = 1;
IF @cmdshellEnabled = 1
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #cmdshell
    (
        txt VARCHAR(255)
    );
    INSERT INTO #cmdshell (txt)
    EXEC xp_cmdshell 'powershell -OutputFormat Text -NoLogo -Command "& {Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\CIMV2" -class Win32_Processor -Property NumberOfCores} | select NumberOfCores"';
    SELECT @CoreCount = CONVERT(INT, LTRIM(RTRIM(txt)))
    FROM #cmdshell
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM(txt)))=1;
    DROP TABLE #cmdshell;
END
IF @CoreCount = 0 
BEGIN
    /* 
        Could not use PowerShell to get the corecount, use SQL Server's 
        unreliable number.  For machines with hyperthreading enabled
        this number is (typically) twice the physical core count.
    */
    SET @CoreCount = (SELECT i.cpu_count from sys.dm_os_sys_info i); 
END

SET @NumaNodes = (
    SELECT MAX(c.memory_node_id) + 1 
    FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks c 
    WHERE memory_node_id < 64
    );

DECLARE @MaxDOP int;

/* 3/4 of Total Cores in Machine */
SET @MaxDOP = @CoreCount * 0.75; 

/* if @MaxDOP is greater than the per NUMA node
    Core Count, set @MaxDOP = per NUMA node core count
*/
IF @MaxDOP > (@CoreCount / @NumaNodes) 
    SET @MaxDOP = (@CoreCount / @NumaNodes) * 0.75;

/*
    Reduce @MaxDOP to an even number 
*/
SET @MaxDOP = @MaxDOP - (@MaxDOP % 2);

/* Cap MAXDOP at 8, according to Microsoft */
IF @MaxDOP > 8 SET @MaxDOP = 8;

PRINT 'Suggested MAXDOP = ' + CAST(@MaxDOP as varchar(max));
```

Comment: The first script returns a blank result. The second returns a suggested `MAXDOP = 2` which is right in line with @sp_BlitzErik. Thanks!