# Lots of short term blockings on SQL Server 2008-R2 database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, blocking, waits

Seeking experts advise on short term blocking which we are seeing for almost a week now.

DB is 15 TB and this Table B where we have lots of blocking - almost 300 in no is 2 TB.

While using sp_whoisactive,  I see queries getting blocked for shorter fraction of 3-4 secs and some in 9-10 secs but because these come and go almost through the day for connections over 2-3 thousand, this causes lots of errors in application.

Troubleshooting done:

- Updated stats on NC index, We just have one NC and one C index.
- While checking from sentry we can see that these blocked statements
  are all insert statements for that table mentioned above.

Below are some metrics:

1. Wait stats for past 3-4 hours where blocking is till on

   - PAGELATCH_EX --> 51.1 % Total waits 730 513 153.5
   - PAGELATCH_SH  --> 23 % Total waits 343 538 769.7
   - THREADPOOL --> 18 % Total waits 257 222 894.4
2. BATCHES/sec on Avg: 8612.6
3. CPU and memory --> well under the threshold as we have 256 logical processors and 612 GB RAM
4. CHECKPOINT pages/sec --> 1706
5. Lazy writes --> 0
6. Log flushes/sec 1844.4
7. Transactions/sec 9074

results as per david's query: Note@ below was run 15 mins after we did node failover

```
 wait_type  wait_time_ms_per_sec
PAGELATCH_EX    733024.4
PAGELATCH_SH    328846.4
CPU_USED    7131.4
WRITELOG    6484.4
DBMIRROR_EVENTS_QUEUE   4973.6
DBMIRRORING_CMD 1456.6
OLEDB   990.2
TRACEWRITE  984.2
SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD 280.6
THREADPOOL  254
ASYNC_NETWORK_IO    45.4
LATCH_EX    9.4
PAGEIOLATCH_EX  7.6
PREEMPTIVE_OS_GETPROCADDRESS    3.4
MSQL_XP 3.2
DBMIRROR_SEND   1.4
PREEMPTIVE_OS_DELETESECURITYCONTEXT 1
PAGELATCH_UP    0.4
PREEMPTIVE_OS_WAITFORSINGLEOBJECT   0.4
PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHORIZATIONOPS  0.2
PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHENTICATIONOPS 0.2
SOS_RESERVEDMEMBLOCKLIST    0.2
CMEMTHREAD  0.2
```

Please provide additional troubleshooting suggestions and let me know if there are any further metrics needed.

Edit@ We are using MAXDOP 8 and Cost threshold of par'sm is set default-5

Update: Did not made any changes as such and when we saw drop in connections during the night time, suddenly issue seem to have vanish and no blocking as checked for now. Below is the stats as of now

```
OLEDB   11883.8
WRITELOG    11732.2
DBMIRROR_EVENTS_QUEUE   4969.8
CPU_USED    4093.75
DBMIRRORING_CMD 1457.2
TRACEWRITE  1080.2
PAGEIOLATCH_SH  333.4
PAGELATCH_EX    237.4
PAGELATCH_SH    31.4
ASYNC_NETWORK_IO    30.2
SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD 6
LATCH_EX    4.4
DBMIRROR_SEND   1.6
PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHENTICATIONOPS 1.4
MSQL_XP 1.2
PREEMPTIVE_OS_GETPROCADDRESS    1.2
PAGELATCH_UP    0.4
PREEMPTIVE_OS_DECRYPTMESSAGE    0.4
SOS_RESERVEDMEMBLOCKLIST    0.4
PREEMPTIVE_OS_DELETESECURITYCONTEXT 0.2
PREEMPTIVE_OS_WAITFORSINGLEOBJECT   0.2
CMEMTHREAD  0.2
PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHORIZATIONOPS  0.2
PREEMPTIVE_OS_CRYPTACQUIRECONTEXT   0.2
PREEMPTIVE_OS_NETVALIDATEPASSWORDPOLICY 0.2
```

Not sure how and why it went as when seeing today we dont see those many connections and neither the blocking. But thats for sure it will pop up soon

Update@ Its back and looks with same waits

[image]

Comment: You might check out [this post by Paul Randal](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/), which discusses wait stats.

Comment: If you have that much [threadpool](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/08/what-are-poison-waits/), you have a lot more to worry about than just blocking. You're running out of worker threads for queries to run. They're most likely related (lots of parallel queries holding threads and being blocked). Also see [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/01/network-issue-threadpool-waits/).

Comment: You need to gather better information.  It's not clear what the problem symptoms are.  Long-running queries?  It's not clear that waits are a problem.  Post better wait data and metrics.  You might try this query https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2013/01/18/my-favorite-query-for-investigating-sql-server-performance/

Comment: And if latch waits really are the issue, whether they are tempdb latch waits, or on some page in your database.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Thanks, let me get the output for that query

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, ive uploaded results. For 1 part of query it returned me 1378 rows so could not paste here. But all of them have wait type PAGELATCH_xx, status suspended and all of them are those insert queires

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Just updated again

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik, thanks for pointing out, but what do you suggest can reduce the threadpool as we have MAXDOP8 and CTOP=5? Would increasing CTOP work or can worse the situation and how much can this be increased

Comment: @RDFozz, thanks. I checked but could not find a way to lower down on PAGELATCH: Any idea ?

Comment: How is your `tempdb` database set up? Multiple database files on separate disk? How are the database's files that you are querying set up? Multiple files? Partitioned?

Comment: @BeginnerDBA - Did you look at [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/10/sql-performance/knee-jerk-wait-statistics-pagelatch) that the `PAGELATCH_XX` page refers to?

Comment: @BeginnerDBA - You also may want to consider bumping up the cost threshold of parallelism; see [this post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/five-sql-server-settings-to-change/) from Brent Ozar's team.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft-- Per your below answer i ran to find wait resource and found it to be under the user db where we see blocking as per db id and file id. I am not sure if i should be using trace 3604 to pull page and table info on PROD to be that safe? How should i proceed from here?

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
wait_type  wait_time_ms_per_sec
PAGELATCH_EX    733024.4
PAGELATCH_SH    328846.4
CPU_USED    7131.4
WRITELOG    6484.4
```

Shows that you have a latch contention problem, and only a latch contention problem.

Since

> @ below was run 15 mins after we did node failover

The CPU_USED row should be accurate.  And so your workload is only managing to use 7sec of CPU time per second.  This is like only running on 7 cores.  In the mean time you have 1000sec of page latch time, meaning that you have, on average 1000 sessions waiting to latch a page, and only 7 performing useful work.

You are also running very old software on a very large server.  The throughput on this server is pretty high, suggesting that the operation it supports is important.  Also consider your username. So you should consider, strongly, engaging Microsoft Support or a partner with expertise in this sort of thing.

That said, the next step is to identify the source of your latch waits.  Generally these are either on a hot page of a table in your database, or a system page in TempDb.  The sys.dm_exec_requests.wait_resource should tell you which.

If tempdb, then [Recommendations to reduce allocation contention in SQL Server tempdb](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2154845/recommendations-to-reduce-allocation-contention-in-sql-server-tempdb-d).

If a table in your database, then post the DDL (including indexes) for the table and a the details of the queries that are blocking.

There is a whitepaper on diagnosing and resolving latch contention on SQL 2008 here: [Diagnosing and Resolving Latch Contention on SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26665)

Comment: Thanks David, Could not find wait resource as there is no blocking going on since last night. Just updated the question as well

Answer (score 3):

51% of your wait is caused by **PAGELATCH_EX** and 23% is caused by **PAGELATCH_SH**.

There is some valuable information about this wait type at [this post](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/pagelatch_ex/).  I'm quoting a little bit here

> This wait type is when a thread is waiting for access to a data file
>   page in memory (usually a page from a table/index) so that it can
>   modify the page structure (EX = EXclusive mode). The Latches
>   Whitepaper in the sidebar on the right has a description of all latch
>   modes and their compatibility with other latch modes.
>
> **Common causes of PAGELATCH_XX contention are:**
>
> - Allocation bitmap contention in tempdb (PAGELATCH_UP for multiple    threads trying to change the same bitmap), and under extreme loads,
>     in user databases
> - Table/index insert hotspot (PAGELATCH_EX for threads inserting onto    the same page and possibly PAGELATCH_SH for threads reading from that 
>     page)
> - Excessive page splits from random inserts (PAGELATCH_EX for threads    trying to insert/update rows on a page and possibly PAGELATCH_SH for
>     threads reading from that page)
>
> There is a [long article on troubleshooting PAGELATCH_XX waits on
>   sqlperformance.com](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/10/sql-performance/knee-jerk-wait-statistics-pagelatch)
>   that covers the first two cases above, basically identifying the cause
>   of the contention from the page resource involved and troubleshooting
>   further from there. Troubleshooting the third case involves figuring
>   out which index is undergoing the page splits and then usually
>   implementing a fill factor and regular index maintenance. You can get
>   the workflow for identifying a table from a page resource (from
>   sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks) in [this blog
>   post](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/finding-table-name-page-id/).

Comment: This is kinda like offering someone Advil when they're having a stroke.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - I originally deleted my post because your comment indicated you thought it wasn't valuable, but it seems that (David Browne - Microsoft)'s answer kind of goes along with my original answer.  Perhaps you could elaborate on your comment so I can understand why you thought it was sub-par?

Comment: I think you're both ignoring a larger problem.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - Perhaps you could post an answer that addresses the _larger problem_?  Your comments seem focused on the _threadpool_ issue.  _Could_ the _threadpool _ issue be a _side effect_ of the PAGELATCH_XX waits?  I'm definitely interested in your comments and really just want to understand these things more.

Comment: _Maybe_. You can _read_ [my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187207/slower-sql-server-performance-after-allocating-more-cpu-and-ram/187209#187209) _here_ if you have _time_.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - I'm happy to read that.  Could you offer your comments on David's answer as well, so he's in the loop regarding your thoughts?

Comment: He doesn't seem to appreciate my feedback, so I'll just keep whistling past the graveyard. I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer here, just FYI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72274/discussion-between-scott-hodgin-and-sp-blitzerik).

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik, i read further on that answer and still not sure where do i need to go further for any change. May be i got confused entirely. So i see max worker thread 1472. so as what i am getting you are saying when load increases[ which i am thinking], would cause bloat up of threads and causing blocking thereafter. so max sessions we can have at a time is 1472? and how do i know if we need to increase max worker thread and increasing would not cause any memory issue?

Comment: @BeginnerDBA if you have a question about THREADPOOL, feel free to post your exact question about it. My response here would be inappropriate.